# PHP - Detect homepage in template of script?

Tags: php, if-statement, html, detect

How to detect home page in php from main index.php of script. So I have that script. This script is main page of script (not template's index.php

```
<?php

$view->title = $LANG["HOMEPAGE_TITLE"];
$view->description = $LANG["HOMEPAGE_DESCRIPTION"];
$view->keywords = $LANG["HOMEPAGE_TAGS"];

if ($view->nav == 'homepage') {
    // ONLY FOR HOME PAGE
    $view->header = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/header.php');
    $view->footer = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/footer.php');
} else { 
    // FOR OTHER ALL PAGE
    $view->header = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/header-common.php');
    $view->footer = $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/footer-common.php');
}

echo $view->render(DIR_TEMPLATE.WEBSITE_TEMPLATE.'/index.php'); //This file home page file
```

I have enter this code but it doesn't detect home page
And I have put this code to index.php (home page). How can I detect is homepage? I have put nav id but it also could not detect.

```
<?php echo $header;?>  
//HOME PAGE CONTENT 
<?php echo $footer;?>
```

Comment: Please format the PHP-code properly (by using line breaks) so it's more readable.

Comment: What is `$view`? Is this something you've built yourself, or are you using a framework of some sort? If you `var_dump($view);` it may give you some clues as to what's contained within this object, and if anything references a home page. Looking at the request URI contained within $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] you may be able to determine if the user is loading your homepage.

Comment: I did such as _SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] but it doesn't work. $wiew is now wiew for header and footer. Can you give full example how to use some ways?

Comment: you need to put in  a variable like $path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ; then you need to echo it out and then make a if statement if it is same as home then is home else is other page

Comment: Can I use if ($view-> for php pages? for example if ($view-> == '/index.php') {

Comment: You _really_ need to show us _all_ the relevant code. If your if-statement doesn't evaluate, then the issue is probably where and how you set the `$view->nav` property? We can't guess what your code look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across the same scenario while doing a project.
This worked for me.

```
<?php

$current_file=  explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$current_file=  end($current_file);

if($current_file=='index.php'){
 // YOUR LOGIC FOR HOME PAGE
} else {
 // YOUR LOGIC FOR ALL OTHER PAGE
}

?>
```

What this script basically does is it will split the url of the form

> http://www.somewebsite.com/index.php

which is provided by

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
```

The splitting is done by the character ' / '.

So the result will be an array of strings.

> http , ' ' , www.somewebsite.com , index.php

We are then checking if the last component of the array is "index.php".

This way we are detecting whether the page is home page or not.

Comment: Thanks for answer!

Comment: If it solved your problem mark it as correct answer.